# Можно ли использовать сенсор отпечатка пальцев для блокировки телефона?

Tags: android, железо, экран

Например я кладу палец на сканер заблокированного телефона - он разблокирывается и включается, потом я опять кладу палец на сканер - телефон блокируется и выключается. Первая половина понятное дело. А вот что со второй?
Конкретная модель - xiaomi redmi note 3. 
P.s. те, кому не понятен вопрос, пожалуйста оставьте комменты, потому что я уже не понимаю как еще объяснить.